# How can I change the location of the imported object without deforming the object?

Tags: import, append

I am new to Blender, and my mother language is not english so it is hard for me to find the answers I need. I have problem with moving an imported object to another place... When I appended or imported new object to my scene in the first time it was not a problem to change a location or scale, but after I add some textures and change pose and then I want to move with that object, it wasnt working. And also I wanted to duplicate this object so I click shift+d, it was ok on the first spot but when I move with this object it was defromed. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: hello, "it wasn't working" is a bit vague, so it's hard to guess what's your problem. As for the second question, maybe you have an armature for your object, it would explain why it deforms when you move it, instead duplicate object + armature and move the armature. Also, if you want the object to share the same mesh, use Alt D (linked duplication) instead of Shift D

Comment: Most likely if there is an armature the imported object is parented to, it will deform if the object is moved and the armature is not. Try selecting both the object and the armature and then move it. If either the armature or the object have animation keyframes, delete them.

Comment: My problem was moving the imported object because the object deformed when the position was changed. Now I know it was because I didn't move the armature. Your answers helped me, thank you very much!